# Function to generate Random letters

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

If there is any built-in function for getting random "letters"

like RANDOM(low,high) we used to generate the random number?

For my typing tutor I want to generate some sentences(which need not to be meaningful).

So I need to get some function to generate letters so that i can generate words from that.

(Change in logic also will be accepted. But I prefer this logic.)

Thank you

Comment: A letter is a number too, so you already have the function. You just need to cast the number to a `char` data type (and select your random numbers from the correct range). Try googling `ascii table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the 'chr()' function, you'll be able to generate ASCII letters.

```
chr(RANDOM(65,90))
```

gives you a random upper-case letter between A and Z,

```
chr(RANDOM(97,122))
```

should give you a lowercase one.

Answer (score 0):

A random character/numer string generation function in Progress based on the answer of LyrixDeRaven. Watch out that it can generate the same random numbers depending on your parameters.

> The Alternate Random Number Generator (-rand) parameter determines whether the same sequence of random numbers is generated for each session. For information on this parameter, see Startup Command and Parameter Reference.

> Above quote From: [RANDOM function PROGRESS documentation](https://From%20https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-122/page/RANDOM-function.html?labelkey=product_openedge_122.).

```
DEFINE VARIABLE result AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

RUN CreateRandomString(INPUT 5, INPUT FALSE).
result = RETURN-VALUE.

PROCEDURE CreateRandomString:
  DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER iAmountCharacters AS INTEGER.
  DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER LCharacters AS LOGICAL.
  
  DEFINE VARIABLE iStep             AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE sString           AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
  
  
  DO iStep = 1 TO iAmountCharacters:
     IF LCharacters THEN
       ASSIGN sString = SUBSTITUTE( "&1&2":U
        , sString
        , CHR(RANDOM(65,90))
        ).
     ELSE
       ASSIGN sString = SUBSTITUTE( "&1&2":U
      , sString
      , STRING(RANDOM(1, 9))
      ).
  END.
  
  RETURN sString.
END PROCEDURE.
```